# Vb.Net Office365 Display Mail

Tags: vb.net, email, office365

How can i programatically get office365  mail(New Message display) to open on a box without a mail client?

Answer (score 0):

You could prcess.start a mailto link to get the default email client to open.  You can set who and what to send in a mail to link

```
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:someone@example.com?subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&body=This%20is%20the%20body")
```

Comment: Hi @Kentucker thanks for the input. There won't be a mail client but users will access their mail from the browser.

Comment: @Moe In the question you say there is a mail client but now you say there is not a mail client. Perhaps you could edit your question to clarify the situation.